# How to only fetch ned rows from a database in SQL? How to only insert rows that are not already in the database?

Tags: python, sql, mariadb

I have two problems that are fairly similar. I am using Python to deal with SQL databases.
First, I want to only fetch the new data from a SQL database (that continously gets updated with new entries). If I have already selected that entire row I don't want it again, just get the new ones. The code I have right now is:

```
sql = ''' SELECT * FROM table WHERE time BETWEEN ? AND ? ''' #Select all columns of the database between the two timestamps
cur.execute(sql,[start_time,end_time])
```

Then I want to insert other data to another database but I don't want to add rows that are already there. My code at the moment is:

```
query = 'INSERT INTO table_2 (col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5, col_6) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'                                                        
my_data = []

for row in data_df:
    my_data.append(tuple(row))
cur.executemany(query, my_data)
```

If have tried to use the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` feature but I am unsure of the syntaxis and I keep getting errors.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: It is a mariadb database

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to help you
What I'm suggesting is to add a column integer in your Table that you can name as STATUS, and initialize it at value 0..
Then you will add a "WHERE" condition like : "WHERE STATUS = 0"
Then you'll UPDATE the selected row at STATUS = 1 (you should do it inside the transition)
If you can't handle the table no problem => you can make a temporary table that contains all the data you're needing and the column with the status
I mean you'll dump all your data in a temporary structure with one more column..